# Are we safe from infection of Bad Rabbit?

Tags: malware, ransomware, wannacry, mimikatz

I'm doing an assessment on the potential outspread of [Bad Rabbit](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/bad-rabbit-ransomware-outbreak-hits-eastern-europe/) in our organization. Our staff do not have admin privileges on their host machines. We have also blocked the IOCs. Am I safe to say without admin privileges, the ransomware wouldn't be able to install the fake flash update/mimikatz?

Any other pointers we need to look out for, other than the ones for WannaCry, Petya, NotPetya?

Comment: Good idea blocking the IOCs. I would also use AppLocker or a SRP via GPO to block any potential variant.

Answer (score 2):

First of all **inform/warn** employees from your organization - not to click on fake flash installation pop-up windows.

Here is an example:

[image]

On welivesecurity.com it is said:

> One of the distribution method of Bad Rabbit is via drive-by download.
>   Some popular websites are compromised and have JavaScript injected in
>   their HTML body or in one of their .js file.

That's from user perspective, now take technical advice:

- keep your software/OS up-to-date
- use strong passwords
- block traffic on SMB protocol (tcp/445)
- use AntiVirus software
- monitor scheduled tasks and service creation

And as @Royce Williams said, you can create following files:

```
c:\windows\infpub.dat && c:\windows\cscc.dat
```

and remove ALL PERMISSIONS (inheritance).

You can also block access to following compromised sites from this list - https://pastebin.com/raw/n7ExrTsJ

More info about badrabbit follow [here](https://gist.github.com/roycewilliams/a723aaf8a6ac3ba4f817847610935cfb).

Answer (score 0):

One specific additional countermeasure is to vaccinate, using [this procedure](https://www.cybereason.com/blog/cybereason-researcher-discovers-vaccine-for-badrabbit-ransomware) to create a couple of specific files:

```
C:\Windows\infpub.dat
C:\Windows\cscc.dat
```

... and then remove permissions inheritance from them.